# How to read spring boot reactive request body from ServerHttpRequest

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm trying with below given code in my project.

```
ServerWebExchange exchange = <already initialized>
Flux<DataBuffer> body= exchange.getRequest().getBody()
```

it returning me empty buffer.

Comment: Does `exchange.getRequest()` has data ?

Comment: @smilyface then how to get body from  exchange.getRequest()

Comment: But you didnt answer my question !

Comment: @smilyface i dont know much ..but it giving me DataBuffer after flat map which is empty

Comment: Ok. Please debug and let us know whether `exchange.getRequest()` contains anything or not. Also in your question it says returning empty data. Is that really empty or null ?

Comment: Could you give more context about this code snippet? Is this in a Controller handler? a filter of some sort? What's the HTTP request for that exchange (headers and body)? What would you expect to get in this case?

Comment: Have you tried adding .log() to get some messaging for debugging? Have you actually subscribed anywhere? As Brian said in other words, we'd need to see the context for your implementation.

Comment: @BrianClozel i have to log each and every request so created WebFilter implementation.

Comment: @ArunKumar you need to write controller to get the request body. Please read [Annotated Controllers](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-controller) and [Functional Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-fn) in the official documentation.